# Move div within child of another div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
    // something
    </div>
</div>

<div id="other-div">
</div>
```

I need to move the "other-div" to be within the "child" class but this has to be done using jQuery. .append or .appendTo only result in the "other-div" going inside the "parent" div.

Comment: It will definitely go into the wrong place if you use the wrong selector!

Comment: If none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#parent .child').append($('#other-div'));
```

will append `#other-div` specifically to `.child`

```js
$('#parent .child').append($('#other-div'));
```

```css
.child{
  background:red;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  }

#other-div{
  background:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    // something
  </div>
</div>

<div id="other-div">
  other div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand your question but i think this will help

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nrh9az4t/

use :

```
$('#parent .child').append($('#other-div'));
```